# Entity Framework Get Count of Dependencies

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of entities I want to display with a flag on each row indicating whether it is possible to delete this particular entity of not - an 'In use' sum of count of records in other tables where this entity id is referenced. > 0 means you can't delete.

Used to do it by stored proc - wondering if there's a EF / Linq way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try something similar to the following:

```
int count = entity.DependencyEntities.Count();
```

---

Refer to:
[Enumerable.Count Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but not sure I'm making myself clear. I'm getting a list of entities from by model and making them the datasource of my repeater. I'd like to have the InUse Count I mentioned available there row by row to set a flag, so I can enable/disable delete button when clicking on row?

Comment: So you have a field called InUse you want to use in enabling/disabling the delete button ?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to calculate and include my Inuse column (a sum of the counts of the foreign keys to my entity in other tables) in EF/ Linq.

Comment: You need to add the InUse field ? Then you need to assign a value to it for each record ?

Comment: Yep, each record having its own count

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if (yourEntity.RelatedEntities.Any(e => e.InUse == true))
{
    // Can't delete
} 
else
{ 
    // Can delete
}
```